# scraping B in <span><span> flow text </span> B </span> using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following bs4 element tag :

```
<span><span>some content</span> B</span>
```

The len of string B is unknown (I named it B for simplification)

How can I use beautifulSoup to extract "b" ? Or I just have as solution to extract the text and then use some regexp techniques

Thanks

Edit : Complete code

```py
def get_doc_yakarouler(license_plate,url = 'https://www.yakarouler.com/car_search/immat?immat='):
    response = requests.get(url+license_plate)
    content = response.content 
    doc = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
    result = doc.span.text
    if 'identifié' in result :
        return doc
    else : 
        return f"La plaque {license_plate} n'est pas recensé sur yakarouler"

doc = get_doc_yakarouler('AA300AA')
span = doc.find_all('span')
motorisation_tag = span[1]
```

I want to extract "1.6 TDI"

I found solution using : motorisation_tag.text.replace(u'\xa0', ' ').split(' ')[1] but I would like if it is directly possible using bs4

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: yes ! it is done

Comment: @Doxcos44 see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs , NavigableString
html = '<span><span>some content</span> B</span>'
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
span = soup.find("span")
# First approach Using Regular Expressions
outer_text_1 = span.find(text=True, recursive=False)
# Second approach is looping through the contents of the tag and check if it's the outer text and not a tag
outer_text_2 = ' '.join([t for t in span.contents if type(t)== NavigableString])

print(outer_text_1) # output B
print(outer_text_2) # output B
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a variable `span` which represents the outer `<span>` tag, you can do the following to extract 'B': `span.contents[1]`. This works because `.contents` will return a list of the tag's contents, in this case `[<span>some content</span>, ' B']`. And then you can access the 'B' text as the second element of the array. Be aware that if there is a space before B, like you showed in your HTML sample, the space will be included in the string

Comment: Thanks you ! So simple